# I need to be able to remove an XML node based on a child attribute value and element value

Tags: xml, xslt, match

I need to filter an XML node by filtering upon a property and an element value.
I need to filter by this:

```
<NameValue name="PrmEAMLocation" type="StringType">true</NameValue>
```

I want to apply an XSLT transformation for the filter, this is my approach, but it is not working:

```
match="ItemLocation[*/NameValue[@name='PrmEAMLocation']='true']"
```

I need to filter by this tag

```
<Property> 
  <NameValue name="PrmEAMLocation" type="StringType">true</NameValue> 
</Property>
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat vague, but to remove the `<Property>` elements that match your criteria, you can use

```
<xsl:template match="Property[NameValue[@name='PrmEAMLocation' and normalize-space(.)='true']]" />
```

This template removes all `<Property>` elements that have a `name` attribute with the value "PrmEAMLocation" and a *leading-and-trailing-space-free* value "true". The other elements/attributes should be copied by the *Identity template*.

**EDIT:**
To also remove a surrounding `<ItemLocation>` element, you can move the `Property` expression into the predicate like this:

```
<xsl:template match="ItemLocation[Property/NameValue[@name='PrmEAMLocation' and normalize-space(.)='true']]" />
```

Comment: Hello, I've testes it and works fine to remove <Property>, however I need to remove the whole parent node ItemLocation and if I change Property by ItemLocation is not working.

Comment: @Ferhache0: I updated my answer with an extended solution matching your requirements. You can understand this better after reading about the [basics of XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).